# How to install latest version of app host on AOSP for Android Automotive OS

Tags: android-auto, android-automotive

I am currently testing by installing AOSP for AAOS and AOSP Automotive App Host on pixel5 phone.

As the AOSP Automotive App Host source is not updated, only car api level 4 or lower features are supported, so I cannot test car api level 5 or higher features on pixel5 phone.

In the case of the AAOS emulator, I can test up to level 6 features by installing the latest version of Google Automotive App Host through the google play store.

Is there any way to install the latest App Host on AOSP for Android Automotive OS?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "play store" on your automotive emulator and sign-in
2. In the play store app, click the menu button upright
3. Choose "My Apps", find "Google Automotive App Host" and install it. It takes some time so be patient.

Now you should be able to run your Android automotive project on the emulator.

[image]
[image]